# generating self signed SSL certifcate, permissions error (OSX)

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, dnsmasq

I'm following [this](http://blog.tarkalabs.com/2014/09/09/setting-up-a-https-dev-workflow-on-osx/) tutorial. I've got DNSMasq working properly but getting a permissions error when trying to generate a self-signed certificate using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
cat &gt; openssl.conf &lt;&lt;-EOF
  [req]
  distinguished_name = site_distinguished_name
  x509_extensions = v3_site
  prompt = no
  [site_distinguished_name]
  CN = *.${PWD##*/}.dev
  [v3_site]
  keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
  extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
  subjectAltName = @domains
  [domains]
  DNS.1 = *.${PWD##*/}.dev
  DNS.2 = ${PWD##*/}.dev
EOF
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 \
  -days 3650 -nodes -x509 -keyout site.key \
  -out site.crt -config openssl.conf
```

Here's what I'm getting in the terminal

```
project_directory $ ./ssl_cert_gen.sh
-bash: ./ssl_cert_gen.sh: Permission denied

project_directory $ sudo ./ssl_cert_gen.sh
Password:
sudo: ./ssl_cert_gen.sh: command not found
```

Am I way off? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the script executable:

```
$ chmod +x ssl_cert_gen.sh
```

All executable files in Unix must have the corresponding executable (`x`) bit set, otherwise the kernel won't execute them. Scripts are executables too, but they utilise the "shebang" mechanism (`#!`) to specify the name of an interpreter.